# How can I remove the start and the end with sed?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, json

How could I remove first ./ and the end / from my path?

right now my code has:

`sed -i 's/dir2\/file-example.json//' test.sh`

and it prints out like this:

`./dir1/`

but I would like to have it like this:

`dir1`

so that it removes the ./ and / from the beginning and end and leaves it with only the directory name.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is there a reason the script is not doing this, or why the path is not given as an argument to the script? Is it easier to modify the actual script than letting the script use simpler parameter expansions to arrive at the needed value?

Comment: You have tagged your question with the [tag:json] tag, yet it does not seem to be about JSON. Would it be ok to remove the tag, or does the question relate to JSON in some way that is currently not obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use the `/` as the regex delimiter, but can fall back to "any other single character" - escaping it. `info sed`:

> '\%REGEXP%'
> (The '%' may be replaced by any other single character.)
>
> ```
>  This also matches the regular expression REGEXP, but allows one to
>  use a different delimiter than '/'.
> ```

In the `s`ubstitute command, you don't even need to escape. Try

```
sed -i 's%\./%%; s%/dir2/file-example.json%%;' test.sh
```

Pls be aware that the dot also has to be escaped to switch off its special meaning in regexes.

Using "back references", this could become even simpler:

```
sed -i 's%\./\(dir1\)/dir2/file-example.json%\1%;' test.sh
```

where the `\1` references back to the first parenthesized partial regex (here: dir1).

Comment: You're quoting the part about `/pattern/ action`. For `s%pattern%replacement%` you don't need, actually don't want to escape the `%`.

Comment: Absolutely. Corrected in answer. Thanks, @Stéphane Chazelas